# Connect to SQL server from client

Tags: sql-server-2012

Currently, I am using the SQL Server 2012 Express version and it is installed on Windows Server 2012 R2. Now I just want to connect to this database from a Windows 7 client. The Windows 7 computer already has its own SQL Server 2012 Express.

When I browse the database from the client, I only see client database's instance name only. There is no server's instance.

I already enabled the Named Pipes and TCP/IP on the server and I am new in that kind of business. So please let me know how can I connect to the SQL Server on the server from the client.

Comment: How are you browsing from the client? If you're selecting "Browse for more" in the SSMS connect dialog, make sure you've selected the Network Servers tab to view machines on the network.

Comment: Yes, I tried,But its also show the only client's database.

Comment: Please take a look at Microsoft's [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). If some step fails, add a screenshot about it. Any error messages are useful too.

Comment: @Loran, the browse functionality is not reliable depending on the network topology. To connect to a remote instance named SQLEXPRESS, you should be table to connect specifying the host and instance name, like "SomeServer\SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: Check that the SQL Browser service is running on the server. If it is not,  the client won't be able to connect using the name of the instance.